# Magento 1.9 Paypal opens before Terms and Condition

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, terms-and-conditions

I have added Paypal as a payment method to my webshop, and I also have configured my webshop to have customers accept Terms and Condition on checkout page.

The problem is, when customer choose Paypal at Step 5 (Payment Information), and then clicking on Continue button, it opens the Paypal payment window immediately without go to Step 6 where customers need to accept Terms and Condition.

[image]

This only happens with Paypal, other payment methods are working fine.

What do I need to do to solve this issue?

Comment: I have this same problem, I don't suppose you managed to get a fix to the issue? Regards
Adam

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143235)

Comment: @AdamHolden I haven't got a solution to this yet. I wonder how other sites using paypal for their Magento 1.9